# Match the summation of two columns, if they match put the value on a cell in a different column

Tags: excel

On `Column A` I have five different amounts and on `Column B` I have another five different amounts. Now on `C1` I want to match the summation of `Column A` and `Column B`, if they match put the value.

What I have tried so far is: `=IFERROR(MATCH(A1:A5,B1:B5,0),0)`

Comment: Yes and if the sum of column A and sum of column B don't match show N/A.

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
=IF(SUM(A1:A5)=SUM(B1:B5),SUM(A1:A5),0)
```